# Структура пакетов в Clean Architecture

Tags: java, android, архитектура

Как правильно раскладывать пакеты в проекте, если используется "Чистая архитектура"? Есть ли какие-то нормальные проекты-примеры реализации Clean Architecture или просто реальные проекты, основанные на этой архитектуре? Все что я видел, было на примере "Hello World" и многое не имело смысла.

---

Евгений Мацюк (не нуждается в представлении), предложил разбить проект на корневые модули (или пакеты, но я буду называть "модулями", имея ввиду корневой пакет, чтобы не путаться):

- **Presentation** — разбит на функции, каждая функция имеет отдельный пакет, каждый пакет имеет подпакеты view и presenter. Возникают воросы: 1. Правильно ли я понял, что функция может иметь несколько экранов? 2. Куда класть разные реализации кастомных View (именно адроидовское View), адаптеров и прочего?
- **Domain** — вопросов очень много и без предварительного просмотра проекта, можно спрашивать очень и очень долго.
- **Repositories** — как я понимаю, пакеты внутри модуля должны быть разбиты по типам данных (Users, News и т.д.). В каждом пакете — свой репозиторий.
- **Data** — в целом, все понятно (как минимум, пока не начал писать).
- **DI** — для меня модуль-загадка. Каждый модуль может иметь свой граф зависимостей и разрастаться по десяткам подпакетов. Если пытаться реализовать модуль DI так, чтобы только он занимался зависимостями, тогда DI должен знать полностью о всем графе зависимостей других модулей. Как-то неправильно.

Так же я не понял, куда класть класс `Application` и классы типа `RxUtils`, `NetworkUtils` с остальными классами-утилитами, доступными на протяжении всего проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идеального решения нет. Все используют варианты, подходящие конкретно под их задачу.

---

Существует два основных подхода к структуре пакетов:

1. Разбитие по слоям
2. Разбитие по функциям

Подробнее о этих двух подходах можно почитать тут — [ссылка](https://fernandocejas.com/2015/07/18/architecting-android-the-evolution/).

---

В качестве проекта-примера можно посмотреть [проект](https://github.com/matzuk/TestableCodeMobius) Евгения Мацюка для Mobius. Так же сейчас сообщество администраторов канала "Clean Architecture` в Telegram разрабатывает реальный проект для демонстрации этой архитектуры в рабочих условиях.